# Can't uninstall Visual Studio 2015 RC Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have been using visual studio 2015 RC community for a little while now, and I found that I can get the full enterprise edition for free from my University. But, after I uninstalled the community edition from the control panel, I still see it in my start menu and it runs as if nothing happened. I saw when searching online, to use the cmd with `/uninstall /force` but I don't know which application to use it on in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` directory to use those on.

Please help me remove this IDE so I can reinstall it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem to solve it I downloaded the latest (out of preview ) community visual studio edition and re ran the setup. Choose repair/modify it may solve the problem.

I will recommend you to use 2013 edition as 2015 still feels incomplete and takes a lot of time perform small operation. Intellisense takes a lot of time to initialize and at so many instance it feels unstable.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer worked, forgot to note that here.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is old, but just in case...

To uninstall "Visual Studio 2015 Community" follow these instructions:

1. Search for vs_community.exe:

   cmd (admin rights) -> `cd C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\` -> `dir /s vs_community.exe`

This will provide you with the exact location of `vs_community.exe`

2. Uninstall:

   `cmd` (admin rights) -> `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{*CODE*}` -> `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force`

More information:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/

NOTE: search vs_community.exe instead of vs_enterprise.exe/vs_ultimate.exe

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

Uninstall Visual Studio
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx

> Alternatively, you can use the "Total Uninstaller" tool to remove
>   everything that Visual Studio or updates to Visual Studio might have
>   installed. That is, any version of Visual Studio 2013 or later. To
>   find out more, see the Visual Studio Uninstaller tool on GitHub.

VisualStudioUninstaller

https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller